# svn add * --force does not add recursive

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

```
svn add * --force
```

I am on window and using Tortoise SVN. I want to add all new files with single task.

I tried all solutions which I found, but that does not add recursively.

I only see add icon on files/directories in current directory only. How can I do this for all sub files/ recursively.

After this command I can not see add (+) icon on subdirectories/files.

I also tried

```
svn add <directory>
```

But this also add only current directory, not its all child.

Comment: Have you tried the option `--depth infinity` ? Because `-force` seems to force recursivity over *versioned* folders only.

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised why the `svn add *` command is not adding its files recursively. Because **recursive adding is default property**. You can see in [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html).

Issue was in properties of my Tortoise-SVN.

I got solution [google issue tracker.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tortoisesvn/GR52pcbOq58)

- Right click in your repo in window. Select `TortoiseSVN > Properties`.
- See if you don't have a property `svn:global-ignores with a value of *`
- If you have property with `star(*)` then it will ignore recursive adding. So remove this property.

This guy [also explained](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tortoisesvn/GR52pcbOq58/DSBEQyU7FCwJ) why this property added in my project.

The most like way that it got there is that someone right-clicked a file without any extension and selected TortoiseSVN -> SVN Ignore -> * (recursively), and then committed this.

> You can check the log to see who committed that property change, find
>   out what they were actually trying to do, and ask them to be more
>   careful in future. :)

Answer (score 0):

Open TortoiseSVN->Properties
Remove property global-ignores